# How to set Focus on Textbox while TextChaged Event in Fired - Asp .Net

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, textbox

I have a form with 2 Text Boxes (along with other controls). Both of them have TextChanged Event. I'm using Tab Key to go from one Control to another.

After entering some value in the first TextBox and then pressing Tab, the focus is not going to Second TextBox.

I'm using `TextBox2.Focus();`

But this is not working.

Your Code is not useful for me. My TextBox does have OnTextChanged Event. I implemented TabIndex, but this is not working after PostBack.

Comment: Check tab index property of your controls.

Comment: @Kedar, Please update your question with the code sample you have mentioned for the comments below. It is difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

Why to do server side code when you can handle it with plain html property [tabindex](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_tabindex.asp)

### Plain Html Code

```
<span>2</span><input type='text' tabindex="1" /><br/>
<span>1</span><input type='text' tabindex="3" /><br/>
<span>3</span><input type='text' tabindex="4" /><br/>
<span>4</span><input type='text' tabindex="2" /><br/>​
```

---

### ASP.NET Code

```
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtField1" runat="server" tabindex="1" />
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtField2" runat="server" tabindex="2" />
```

[For working demo see here](http://jsfiddle.net/QczSt/1/)

Comment: Your Code is not useful for me. My TextBox does have OnTextChanged Event. I implemented TabIndex, but this is not working after PostBack.   <asp:TextBox ID="txt_projectValue" runat="server" CssClass="txtboxes" ValidationGroup="anj"
                        AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txt_projectValue_TextChanged" TabIndex="4"></asp:TextBox>           <asp:TextBox ID="txt_projectExpenses" runat="server" CssClass="txtboxes" ValidationGroup="anj"
                        OnTextChanged="txt_projectExpenses_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="True" TabIndex="5"></asp:TextBox>